# How do I override an existing plugin in ImageJ ? I have a custom reader for an already existing format

Tags: java, plugins, imagej, overriding

I am using the CSI DM3 Reader ( http://code.google.com/p/cornell-spectrum-imager/wiki/Home ) to read my .dm3 files. I would like to add drag & drop functionality for this, so I changed the file HandleExtraFileTypes.java ( http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/HandleExtraFileTypes.java ) and changed its .dm3 association in lines 101 - 103 from

```
    if (name.endsWith(".dm3") && buf[0]==0 && buf[1]==0 && buf[2]==0 && buf[3]==3) {
        return tryPlugIn("DM3_Reader", path);
    }
```

to

```
    if (name.endsWith(".dm3") && buf[0]==0 && buf[1]==0 && buf[2]==0 && buf[3]==3) {
        return tryPlugIn("CSI_DM3_Reader", path);
    }
```

**This opens the file in both the CSI DM3 Reader as well as the standard DM3 reader, and I want it to open only in the CSI DM3 Reader. How do I suppress ImageJ opening its regular DM3 reader ?**

Note : The tryPlugIn object is as follows

```
/**
* Attempts to open the specified path with the given plugin. If the
* plugin extends the ImagePlus class (e.g., BioRad_Reader), set
* extendsImagePlus to true, otherwise (e.g., LSM_Reader) set it to false.
*
* @return A reference to the plugin, if it was successful.
*/
private Object tryPlugIn(String className, String path) {
    Object o = IJ.runPlugIn(className, path);
    if (o instanceof ImagePlus) {
        // plugin extends ImagePlus class
        ImagePlus imp = (ImagePlus)o;
            if (imp.getWidth()==0)
                o = null; // invalid image
            else
                width = IMAGE_OPENED; // success
    } else {
        // plugin does not extend ImagePlus; assume success
        width = IMAGE_OPENED;
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Silly question but after changing `HandleExtraFileTypes.java` you rebuilt ImageJ right?

Comment: Oh yes, of course :) Fair enough that you checked that with me.

Comment: I'd recommend running it through an IDE like Eclipse where you can run in debug mode. Put a break point in the HandleExtraFileTypes.java class and see where it is opening the file. The debug mode in ImageJ can be informative too.

Comment: @medPhys-pl Thanks a lot. That sounds useful. I've set up ImageJ as an Eclipse project, but I've been working on another project over the last while so I didn't think of this. I'll keep you posted when I do test this out. Thanks again :)